# Passando um nome de EditView para um TextView entre fragments

Tags: android

Galera, eu tô com um projeto que usa um navigation drawer, então o implements da MainActivity já está "ocupado", por isso muitos métodos de fazer isso não dão certo no meu caso. Tenho um MainActivity que controla os fragmentos que uso. Em um fragmento tenho um EditText que vai receber um nome digitado pelo usuário e outro que receberá esse nome e o exibirá.

Fragment EditarNome

```
public class EditarNome extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
private EditText editarNome;
private Button enviar;
String oi;
conexao con;

View rootview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editar, container, false);
    editarNome = (EditText) rootview.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.editarNome);
    oi = editarNome.getText().toString();

    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    con = (conexao) Inicio);
    enviar = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    enviar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    con.resposta(oi);
}
```

}

Fragment Inicio (é a Activity que usei para gerenciar o fragment InicioFragment)

```
public class Inicio extends FragmentActivity implements conexao {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inicio);
}
@Override

public void resposta(String data) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    InicioFragment frag = (InicioFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    frag.changeText(data);

}
```

}

Fragment InicioFragment (onde quero exibir o nome)

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {
TextView text;
View rootview;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    text = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.campoData2);
}

public void changeText(String data) {
    text.setText(data);
}
```

}

Interface conexao

public interface conexao {
    public void resposta(String data);
}

O erro que o Android diz é no fragment EditarNome, quando chamo a Activity Inicio.
Espero que possam me ajudar!
Vlw

Comment: Adiciona o log com o erro que gerou

Answer (score 0):

Vou colocar alguns possiveis problemas.

**Fragment EditarNome**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    con = (conexao) Inicio);//um parenteses aqui abandonado, e tambem não entendi o que vc quis fazer nessa linha, vc nao instanciou a classe
    enviar = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    enviar.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

**Fragment Inicio**

```
public void resposta(String data) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    InicioFragment frag = (InicioFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    frag.setData(data);  
}
```

**Fragment InicioFragment**

```
String data;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    text = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.campoData2);
    text.setText(data);
}
public void setData(String data){
   this.data=data;
}
```

Comment: Nessa linha con = (conexao) Inicio, eu quero que conexao se "conecte" com a Activity Inicio. Por exemplo, se fosse com a MainActivity eu colocava um getActivity() e pronto, mas o problema é que quero ligar com outra Activity e não sei como.

Comment: Coloca o código completo da MainActivity